# How to have Swap in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows

How to have Swap in Windows 7 Ultimate. I want to use my little `HDD` as swap
thanks and regards
Portia

Answer (score 2):

In Windows it is called page file, you can change it in the advanced system settings.

Please find more information here.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7